# texturing multiple meshes in a single vbo

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

i have this Vertex Buffer Object containing vertex(position, normal, and UV) and index data that is used to draw 3 different meshes. now i want to apply a different texture to each mesh. problem is that i only know how to render one texture on a Vertex Buffer Object. how do i go about texturing each of them differently and doing it efficiently regardless of the difficulty. is there some kind of texture buffer object for me to load the textures into and then coordinate with the Vertex Buffer Object.

Comment: one idea is to build one big texture from the 3 separate ones and use texture coordinates to choose correct one. Sprite sheets are one example of this technique.

Comment: sounds like the solution i'm looking for. only problem is i a not skilled enough to implement it. how would i go about implementing it in an object oriented fashion? for example `texture_buffer.Add(tex1);` with tex1 being the raw image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different starts/counts in your `glDrawArrays()` calls, with texture binds in between:

```
glBindTexture( ..., texture1 );
glDrawArrays( ..., obj1_start, obj1_vert_count );
glBindTexture( ..., texture2 );
glDrawArrays( ..., obj2_start, obj2_vert_count );
glBindTexture( ..., texture3 );
glDrawArrays( ..., obj3_start, obj3_vert_count );
```

Comment: Im using glDrawElements to render my data

Comment: The same logic applies.  Bind the texture and pass in a pointer to the appropriate indices.